# Bind ajax values directly to GridView text

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms, aspxgridview

I have some values that C# returns through json to ajax.
And I need to bind this values in a GridView.

Json code:

```
d   […]
0   {…}
ObjectID      1
ObjectName    Vegas
ObjectValue   234
Object        Arizona
1   {…}
ObjectID      2
ObjectName    Chicago
ObjectValue   211
Object        Montana
2   {…}
ObjectID      3
ObjectName    Livepool
ObjectValue   123
Object        London
...
```

And this is the ajax code:

```
 $(document).on('click', ".myButton", function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Administrations.aspx/Collection",
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'Parameter2': Parameter2 }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.d.length > 0) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, values) {

                        values.ObjectID;
                        values.ObjectName;
                        values.ObjectValue;
                        values.Object;
                        console.log(values);
                    });

                }
                console.log("Saved!");
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("Not Saved!");
           }

        });
    });
```

I need somehow to bind those ajax values:

```
(values.ObjectID; values.ObjectName; values.ObjectValue; values.Object;)
```

to GridView text bound fields:

```
( Text='<%# Bind("ObjectID") %>'> , Text='<%# Bind("ObjectName") %>'>, Text='<%# Bind("ObjectValue") %>'> , Text='<%# Bind("Object") %>'>
```

that are located in gvMyObjects GridView below.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvMyObjects" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" CssClass="GridView" AutoPostBack="False"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" >

            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>

                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
                        <button class="myBtn" id="Button1" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"  runat="server" ><span>Select</span></button>
 </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="ObjectID" runat="server"   margin-Left="100px"  Text='<%# Bind("ObjekatID") %>'></asp:Label>


                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <asp:Label ID="ObjectName" runat="server" margin-Left="100px" Text='<%# Bind("ObjectName") %>'></asp:Label>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value">
                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <asp:Label ID="ObjectValue" runat="server" margin-Left="100px" Text='<%# Bind("ObjectValue") %>'></asp:Label>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value">
                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <asp:Label ID="Object" runat="server" margin-Left="100px" Text='<%# Bind("Object") %>'></asp:Label>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>


        </asp:GridView>
```

Can someone please help me with this ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you bind your collection directly to you Gridview directly to your collection ?